# using loop get the hashmap values

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, hashmap

I have 5 attributes in my database, I am trying to retrieve it using `hashmap` in my struts2 project. Attributes are named `MarketPlace`, `OrderDate`, `dataamount`, `count`, `result`. Here I want to show the values in my jsp table, so each `marketplace` has 3 span rows, which has the value of `dataamount`, `count`, `result`.
Currently my java action class look like this.

```
package com.action;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import com.action.GetCon;
import com.action.ReportClass;

import freemarker.debug.Breakpoint;

public class JanuaryAction {
private String name;
HashMap abc = new HashMap();

public HashMap getAbc() {
return abc;
}
public void setAbc(HashMap abc) {
this.abc = abc;
}
public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String execute() throws Exception{

String time=getName();
 /*   System.out.println(time);*/
if(time.equals("January 2013")){

abc.put(time,"'2013-01-01' AND OrderDate <= '2013-01-31'" );
}
else if(time.equals("February 2013")){
abc.put(time,"'2013-02-01' AND OrderDate <='2013-02-31'" );
}
else if(time.equals("March 2013")){
abc.put(time,"'2013-03-01' AND OrderDate <='2013-03-31'" );
}
else if(time.equals("April 2013")){
abc.put(time,"'2013-04-01' AND OrderDate <='2013-04-31'" );
}
else if(time.equals("May 2013")){
abc.put(time,"'2013-05-01' AND OrderDate <='2013-05-31'" );
}
else if(time.equals("June 2013")){
abc.put(time,"'2013-06-01' AND OrderDate <='2013-06-05'" );
}
String newtime=(String)abc.get(time);
   /* System.out.println(newtime);*/

Connection con = GetCon.getCon();
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >=" +newtime+ " GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace") ;
Object value = abc.remove(time);

while(resultset.next()){

String marketplace = resultset.getString(1);

String orderdate = resultset.getString(2);

Double datamount = resultset.getDouble(3);
Integer count= resultset.getInt(4);

Double result=resultset.getDouble(5);

abc.put(0, marketplace);
String value1 = (String) abc.get(0);
System.out.println(value1);


abc.put(1, orderdate);
String value2 = (String) abc.get(1);
System.out.println(value2);


abc.put(2, datamount);
Double value3 = (Double) abc.get(2);
System.out.println(value3);


abc.put(3, count);
Integer value4 = (Integer) abc.get(3);
System.out.println(value4);


abc.put(4, result);
Double value5 = (Double) abc.get(4);
System.out.println(value5); }

return "success";
}}
```

Comment: Set the `List` or `Map` in `request` or `session` scope and iterate through the values using JSTL in JSP. There are tons of tutorials to get started.

Comment: Ok, what is the question here???

Comment: You forget to say what database is.

Comment: the question is how to get the values in jsp page, i have used println statements in java class so i was able to see 1000 of values, same values i wanna see even in jsp page. mysql database

Comment: Now, post the DDL for your schema objects.

Comment: [data definition language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language)

Comment: SELECT MarketPlace,OrderDate, ROUND(SUM(Total),2), COUNT(*) , ROUND(ROUND(SUM(Total),2)/ COUNT(*),2) FROM vend_printed WHERE OrderDate >=" +newtime+ " GROUP BY OrderDate,MarketPlace

Comment: you can create DTO and create arraylist in action class, set this list of DTO from database. Then in jsp you can iterate over the list to show values in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<s:iterator var="studentEntry" status="stat" value="map.entrySet()">  <br><br><br>
Marketplace Name is: <s:property value="%{#studentEntry.getKey()}"/> <br>
Value: <s:property value="%{#studentEntry.getValue()}"/><br><br><br>

</s:iterator>
```

hope this helps.